# in mobile web app: is it possible to use "get directions" link that leads to Navigating with waze?

Tags: mobile, gps, maps, mobile-website

If i want to include "get directions" link in web site - is it possible to use waze in order to get instructions with the link?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with the waze.to URL api.

The following format is working, both for Android and iOS:

http://waze.to/?ll=latitude,longitude&navigate=yes

Example:
http://waze.to/?ll=48.149491,17.108636&navigate=yes

More information :

- http://world.waze.com/dev/documentation/
- http://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=17684